# Show the Loader where the content within the div loads not when the entire page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically, I'm getting data and  I'm looking for showing the loader where the data will be reside until the data loads not when the entire page loads...

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  $(".loader").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

```css
  .loader {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 9999;
  background: url('https://image') 50% 50% no-repeat rgb(249, 249, 249);
  .no-js .loader {
    display: none;
  }
  .js .loader {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- This loader class will run until the full page loads, how can I customize it to load where, I will be getting the data.. -->
<div class="loader"></div>
<!-- here's the first div -->
<div>Content</div>
<!-- here's the Second div -->
<div>Content</div>
<!-- here's the third div, where I'm getting the data -->
<div>Content</div>
```

Comment: is the data coming asynchronously?

Comment: are you using ajax to load data ?

Comment: @Greedo No, Data's coming from Mysql database...

Comment: @Niteesh No, Data's is coming from Mysql Database and I'm not using any ajax

Comment: in that case all the page won't be rendered until all PHP computation are completed. You can achieve what you want with ajax loading

Comment: @Greedo why do I need to use ajax to get data ???..I'm getting data.All I want is how to show the loader on the specific place until the data loads..

Comment: the full page/section won't load until all PHP is compiled